# how do you declare an array of objects inside typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I would like to specify a function that takes an array of objects as a parameter, but I don't have a particular type defined for the object (a sort of "anonymous type")

```
bagTotal = (products) => {
 // function does stuff
}
```

I understand I can do this:

```
bagTotal = (products: any[]) => {
 // function does stuff
}
```

but this is a bit more relaxed then what I want: to be strict with typescript.

`products` is an array of the same-looking objects; all objects have a name, a price and a description.

how can I declare that?

I want to do something like

```
bagTotal = (products: [{name: string, price: number, description: string}]) => {
 // function does stuff
}
```

but that's not right. How can I declare this?

Comment: Why did you say it is not right ?

Comment: Your solution creates a tuple consisting of an object with a given interface.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You're almost there, the placement of the brackets is just wrong:

```
{name: string, price: number, description: string}[]
```

The way you had it isn't entirely wrong, but it means something else: it means an array with exactly one item of this type.

---

I'd also recommend extracting it to an interface, it'd make the type reusable and the thing easier to read:

```
interface Product {
    name: string;
    price: number;
    description: string;
}

const products: Product[];
```

Comment: I would recommend using the `Array<T>` form if the item type is very large : `Array<{name: string, price: number, description: string}>`

Comment: I just added that I'd actually extract a type for it anyway ;)

Comment: @IngoBürk I slighted edited my question. please see. I can accept your answer if you answer that, thanks

Comment: @Red Baron products in your interface is still untyped, so what's the point? Also I'm rolling back that edit. Please don't change the question fundamentally after receiving answers. You asked a question, it has been answered. For a new question please open a new question.

Comment: ok I'll open a new question when it allows me too and accept this one. thanks

Answer (score 6):

The [generic array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) `Array<elemType>` provides a straightforward way to declare an array of objects:

```
bagTotal = (products: Array<{name: string, price: number}>) => {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you must declare the class "Product" so you can declare a Product array like this:

```
products: Product[];
```

and pass it as a parameter like this:

```
bagTotal = (products: Product[]) => {
 // function does stuff
}
```

To have the class you can do a new .ts file with this code:

```
export class Product {
  name: String;
  price: Number;
  description: String;
}
```

I wish that helped!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are declaring an array of a specific object and want to specify type for variables in the objects, I would create a class for the object like this:

```
class Item(){
    name: string;
    description: string;
    etc: any

  constructor() {
    this.name;
    this.description;
    this.etc;
}}
```

Then you can specify the array as an array of item objects:

```
itemArray: Array<Item>;
```

Comment: What if the array of objects should be generic?