# Type '(props: Props) => Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<Props>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add TypeScript in a React app.

Versions:

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"typescript": "3.5.3",
```

I have an array like

```
import aLogo from '../images/a.svg';
import bLogo from '../images/b.svg';

const websites = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    src: aLogo,
    url: 'https://a.com',
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    src: bLogo,
    url: 'https://b.com',
  },
];
```

I am passing it to a component through props.

```
interface Website {
  name: string;
  src: string;
  url: string;
}

interface Props {
  websites: Website[];
}

const SocialList: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const { websites } = props;

  return websites.map((website) => {
    const { name, src, url } = website;

    return (
      <a key={name} href={url}>
        <img src={src} />
      </a>
    );
  });
};
```

But it gives me error

```
TypeScript error in /SocialList.tsx(16,7):
Type '(props: Props) => Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<Props>'.
  Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>': type, props, key  TS2322

    14 | }
    15 | 
  > 16 | const SocialList: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
       |       ^
```

I read the answers in [how do you declare an array of objects inside typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964694/how-do-you-declare-an-array-of-objects-inside-typescript), but still cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: `Array<Website>`

Comment: @zynkn just tried to change `Website[]` to `Array<Website>`, still got same error.

Comment: What are you returning from `SockailList` ? do you do something like `return websites.map(...)` ?

Comment: @AsafAviv yeah, just added in the question.

Comment: `const websites: Array<Website> = [...]`

Comment: I found this googling "Initializer type (props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | string | number | {} | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined is not assignable to variable type React.FC<Props>" end accepted answer helped me resolve this issue

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Your `SocialList` component renders multiple nodes. While this behavior is supported in React version >=16.0, it is not allowed by the type declarations for React (`@types/react`). In other words, you can render multiple nodes in JS React (v16+), but not in TS React. For JS React, see the related question: [Return multiple elements inside React.render()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34893506/8068625).

To fix this, you have a few options: either update your component so that it only returns a single node, use a type assertion, or disable the error from TypeScript.

#### Returning a Single Node

You can update your code to return the `a` tags within a containing element. The default used to be to use `div`, but this clutters the DOM. Instead you can use the [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) component, which does not render anything to the actual DOM, and is therefore basically what you're after.

Example:

```
const SocialList: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const { websites } = props;

  const websiteElements = websites.map((website) => {
    const { name, src, url } = website;

    return (
      <a key={name} href={url}>
        <img src={src} />
      </a>
    );
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {websiteElements}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
};
```

You can also use the [short syntax for fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) as below if you prefer:

```js
<>
  {websiteElements}
</>
```

#### Type Assertion

You can assert the type of the return value to be `any`, which will cause the type error to be ignored. This will, however, conflict with the eslint rule [no-explicit-any](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any/) if you have that enabled (which is a rule I disagree with). Anyway I don't recommend this approach because you should try to avoid `as any` as much as possible (and here it is possible to avoid).

Example:

```
const SocialList: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const { websites } = props;

  return websites.map((website) => {
    const { name, src, url } = website;

    return (
      <a key={name} href={url}>
        <img src={src} />
      </a>
    );
  }) as any;
};
```

#### Disable the Error

Since the error is just due to the type declarations from `@types/react` you can [suppress the TS error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) by putting `// @ts-ignore` above the errored line.  You could try to find a more specific error to ignore, but I couldn't find it for this case, so be careful as this will ignore *all* TS errors on that line (e.g. if `Props` accepts a type param but is not given one).

I don't recommend this approach because disabling TS errors should be avoided as much as possible, and from [the TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments):

> Please note that this comment only suppresses the error reporting, and we recommend you use this comments very sparingly.

Example:

```
// @ts-ignore
const SocialList: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const { websites } = props;

  return websites.map((website) => {
    const { name, src, url } = website;

    return (
      <a key={name} href={url}>
        <img src={src} />
      </a>
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 9):

The error is about returning an array of JSX elements which is not a valid return type from a component.

You must return a single node, all you have to do is wrap it inside a fragment `<></>` or a `<div></div>` etc...

Also you don't need to type `props` parameter again

```
const SocialList: React.FC<Props> = ({ websites }) => (
  <>
    {websites.map(({ name, src, url }) => (
      <a key={name} href={url}>
        <img src={src} />
      </a>
    ))}
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer here is not correct as for the reason you get this error. React components *can* return arrays containing React elements as of React v16. You *don't have to* return a Fragment.

This is an issue with the react types package, and more specifically an issue with TS itself.

[source 1](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41808#issuecomment-577688016)
[source 2](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699)

As a workaround, you can either suppress this error message, since it is erroneous in itself, or, indeed, return a Fragment

Comment: Just curious, how would you suppress this error message?

Comment: You can add the line // @ts-ignore above the line that throws the TS error. It's safe to do so, since this is not an actual error in React.

Answer (score 1):

How is array of JSX elements not a valid return type? This whole conversation looks weird, because returning an array from render was added back in 2017 with the release of React@16.

T'was rather disappointing, finding this instead of a real solution.

Guess the react typing was just not updated after React@16. In my code I had to fix it like this:

```
type AdvFC<P> = (...args: Parameters<React.FC<P>>) => ReturnType<React.FC<P>> | ReturnType<React.FC<P>>[];
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
const SocialList: React.AdvFC<Props> = (props: Props) => ...
```

No idea if that brings some side effects, so far so good.

Comment: In the React documentation it states that even if you want to return an array of components you should wrap it inside a fragment. See the documentation on fragments for more details: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html